# Why canvas function draws grid with double lines?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

I have a functon that draws a grid in canvas.
The below has default config, that applied for drawing a canvas rectangle with grid lines.

```
const defaultConfig: GridOptions = { color: '#000000', gridSize: 4, gridPadding: 0, strokeStyle: '#00000' };

export function CrossTemplate(
  gridOptions: Partial<GridOptions> = defaultConfig,
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
): HTMLCanvasElement {
  const config = { ...defaultConfig, ...gridOptions };
  const bw = canvas.width;
  const bh = canvas.width;
  const p = 0;
  const cw = bw + p * 2 + 1;
  const ch = bh + p * 2 + 1;

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = ch;
  canvas.width = cw;

  if (!context) throw Error('Canvas context error');

  for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
  }

  for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = config.strokeStyle;
  context.stroke();

  return canvas;
}
```

I get always a dobule line (pic.1)

[image]

Where did I mistake in calculations?

https://jsfiddle.net/dLqe76op/10/

Comment: Probably the effect of rounding, because you are working with `0.5` pixels?

Comment: Probably yes, how to fix it? I use it for step

Comment: I have tried rremove 0.5 everywhere, the same result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dLqe76op/10/